# PHP Regex: How to strip all HTML tags but not non HTML tags?

Tags: php, regex, string

Using PHP regex, how can I removed HTML tags (both opening and closing) and with attributes like `<hr class="myclass" />` without removing non HTML tags like `<dog>` or `<dog class="cat">`?

The non HTML tags are dynamic and cannot be hard coded.

Input:

```
<b><> <<> <dog> <123> <" !> <!--...--> <!doctype> <hr class="myclass" /> </b>
```

Output should be:

```
<> <<> <dog> <123> <" !>
```

I'm considering to use HTML Purifier but first I need to know if this is possible in regex.

HTML Tag reference: http://www.quackit.com/html/tags/

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: @Maerlyn: Using strip_tags will remove also non HTML tags.

Comment: @marknt15: You didn't read the manual then. It has an optional second parameter giving you the ability to specify a list of tags _not_ to be removed. Now this isn't quite what the OP wants, but it's an approach.. especially if he knows the input domain well.

Comment: @Tomalak: The list of tags not be removed are dynamic and I don't know all of them like <777>. I have to check millions of records to know all of those and I don't want to hard code them :)

Comment: @marknt15: Sounds like a poor design to mix "arbitrary XML-like tags" with real HTML. Where are you putting this text, that the HTML is dangerous but the arbitrary tags are not?

Comment: Manipulating DOM trees with regex is bad and wrong. Don't!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To match (and remove) start and end tags for HTML 4.01 elements only, the regex in this tested PHP function will do a pretty darn good job:

```php
function strip_HTML_tags($text)
{ // Strips HTML 4.01 start and end tags. Preserves contents.
    return preg_replace('%
        # Match an opening or closing HTML 4.01 tag.
        </?                  # Tag opening "<" delimiter.
        (?:                  # Group for HTML 4.01 tags.
          ABBR|ACRONYM|ADDRESS|APPLET|AREA|A|BASE|BASEFONT|BDO|BIG|
          BLOCKQUOTE|BODY|BR|BUTTON|B|CAPTION|CENTER|CITE|CODE|COL|
          COLGROUP|DD|DEL|DFN|DIR|DIV|DL|DT|EM|FIELDSET|FONT|FORM|
          FRAME|FRAMESET|H\d|HEAD|HR|HTML|IFRAME|IMG|INPUT|INS|
          ISINDEX|I|KBD|LABEL|LEGEND|LI|LINK|MAP|MENU|META|NOFRAMES|
          NOSCRIPT|OBJECT|OL|OPTGROUP|OPTION|PARAM|PRE|P|Q|SAMP|
          SCRIPT|SELECT|SMALL|SPAN|STRIKE|STRONG|STYLE|SUB|SUP|S|
          TABLE|TD|TBODY|TEXTAREA|TFOOT|TH|THEAD|TITLE|TR|TT|U|UL|VAR
        )\b                  # End group of tag name alternative.
        (?:                  # Non-capture group for optional attribute(s).
          \s+                # Attributes must be separated by whitespace.
          [\w\-.:]+          # Attribute name is required for attr=value pair.
          (?:                # Non-capture group for optional attribute value.
            \s*=\s*          # Name and value separated by "=" and optional ws.
            (?:              # Non-capture group for attrib value alternatives.
              "[^"]*"        # Double quoted string.
            | \'[^\']*\'     # Single quoted string.
            | [\w\-.:]+      # Non-quoted attrib value can be A-Z0-9-._:
            )                # End of attribute value alternatives.
          )?                 # Attribute value is optional.
        )*                   # Allow zero or more attribute=value pairs
        \s*                  # Whitespace is allowed before closing delimiter.
        /?                   # Tag may be empty (with self-closing "/>" sequence.
        >                    # Opening tag closing ">" delimiter.
        | <!--.*?-->         # Or a (non-SGML compliant) HTML comment.
        | <!DOCTYPE[^>]*>    # Or a DOCTYPE.
        %six', '', $text);
}
```

**CAVEATS:** Does not remove scripts `<? ... ?>`. Will remove any start or end tags occurring in these structures. Does not correctly parse generalized SGML compliant comments. Does not handle shorttags.

**EDIT:** Added matching for DOCTYPE and (non-SGML-strict) HTML comments. It now correctly passes the test data in the OP.

**EDIT2** The previous version was missing the `'s'` single-line modifier. Also added shorttags to caveats list.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and turning on the [`HTML.Proprietary` option](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.Proprietary), then using the [`HTML.Allowed` option](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.Allowed) to *expressly whitelist* the specific tags and attributes you wish to keep.

Remember, using regular expressions to parse HTML can easily invoke the wrath of Zalgo.  Do not taunt Zalgo.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function called [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). It removes all HTML tags, so it will keep your "custom" tags. If not, tags which you do not wish to remove can be specified.

Comment: "If not, tags which you do not wish to remove can be specified." <--- it is dynamic and don't know all of them so I cannot hard code it.

Comment: "so it will keep your "custom" tags" is wrong, as you go on to clarify in your final sentence.

Comment: @marknt15: Consider a "whitelist" policy instead. Tell your users which tags they _may_ use. This reversal will (a) allow this simple solution, and (b) be better for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative working solution by Dhon:

```
<?php
$exemption_array = array('<a href"http://www.autopartswarehouse.com/search/?searchType=global&N=0&Ntt=A1327630">');
function strip_HTML_tags_withExemptions( $str , $arrayExemption = array() ){
     //Notes $arrayExemption holds all string exemptions in form of tags example <a href"http://www.autopartswarehouse.com/search/?searchType=global&N=0&Ntt=A1327630">
    foreach( $arrayExemption as $k => $exemptions )
        $str = str_replace($exemptions, " " , $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/<\/?(!DOCTYPE|a|abbr|acronym|address|applet|area|article|aside|audio|b|base|basefont|bdo|big|blockquote|body|br|button|canvas|caption|center|cite|code|col|colgroup|command|datalist|dd|del|details|dfn|dir|div|dl|dt|em|embed|fieldset|figcaption|figure|font|footer|form|frame|frameset|h\d|head|header|hgroup|hr|html|i|iframe|img|input|ins|keygen|kbd|label|legend|li|link|map|mark|menu|meta|meter|nav|noframes|noscript|object|ol|optgroup|option|output|p|param|pre|progress|q|rp|rt|ruby|s|samp|script|section|select|small|source|span|strike|strong|style|sub|summary|sup|table|tbody|td|textarea|tfoot|th|thead|time|title|tr|tt|u|ul|var|video|wbr|xmp)((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>|<!--(.)*-->/i" , " ", $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str );
    $str = preg_replace('/[\.]+/', '.', $str );
    return $str;
}
?>
```

Comment: Other than the main regex being unreadable, not bad. However the dot-star in the comment subexpression (`<!--(.)*-->`) is too greedy and will consume good stuff appearing between multiple comments (on one line). It also fails to match multi-line comments. To fix this, change the expression to: `<!--.*?-->` and add the `'s'` modifier. (Note: my regex was also missing the `'s'` modifier - thanks for this answer otherwise I never would have found it!)

Comment: Sorry to pick nits, but this one also fails to match real-life `<!DOCTYPE...>`s (which don't have tag-like attribute name=value pairs) e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Comment: Thanks ridgerunner for the additional fix. I will try it :)